# PYTHON minutes from timestamp

Tags: python, timestamp, python-3.3

I simply need a decimal system to count time with the precision of the minute.

So I need a function that returns the number of minutes from the timestamp (for timestamp I mean 1/1/1970).

It have to be very simple, on the contrary I'm searching from 25 minutes!

Comment: Whats the issue with [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module?

Comment: yes, that's the library that I'm trying to use...

Comment: Again, what is the issue with it? what are you not able to achieve with it?

Comment: I need the minutes from the timestamp: a function that return the number of minutes from the timestamp (for timestamp I mean 1/1/1970)

Comment: You may have a terminology misunderstanding here. What you describe as a *timestamp* is generally referred to as *epoch*. A timestamp is something different, namely a time value that describes when a certain event happened.

Comment: @oefe: timestamp might mean POSIX timestamp in the context of `datetime` module. See [`datetime.timestamp()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp)

Answer (score 2):

```
import time
print(int(time.time() / 60))

23078330
```

Comment: or just `time.time() // 60` if you don't mind a float result and the difference between `floor()` and `trunc()` doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime as DT
def minutes(timestamp=None):
    """ Return integral number of minutes from the Epoch, 1970-1-1 """
    if timestamp is None:
        now = DT.datetime.now()
        timestamp = now.timestamp()
    return timestamp//60

print(minutes())
```

Comment: timestamp isn't in the standard libraries of python (it seems, but I can't believe it) I try this `from datetime import timestamp` but don't work. What I have to do?

Comment: [datetime.timestamp](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) is available if you are using Python3.3.

Comment: so python really need 7 lines to have a decimal system in time? I'm a noob in this but if this is the only way i dislike a lot this language...anyway thanks to you, it's not your fault

Comment: yes I'm using python 3.3.2 but how can I use datetime.timestamp to get the minutes?

Comment: Python values readability, not terseness. Still, a stripped down version could be written as a one-liner: `lambda: DT.datetime.now().timestamp//60`.

Comment: so isn't really possible to have a line to do this with standard libraries and readable?!...(anyway I don't be able to run that line...)

Comment: The Python way would be to put it in a file and import it yourself. Then it is readable and simple to use. If you don't like that, you should find a language you like better.

Comment: It's very strange because the computer certainly count the time with a decimal system, only after will convert in the idiot year,month,day,minutes,second system....I really can't believe that.

What does is means `lambda:` how can I use that code?


Ps I don't understand what do you say? What do you mean with "The Python way would be to put it in a file and import it yourself." what I have to put in a file?